# Add source to an existing automake program

Tags: c++, c, makefile, automake

I would like to edit an existing software to add a new source file (Source.cpp). 
But, I can't manage the compilation process (it seems to be automake and it looks very complicated).

The software (iperf 2: https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/files/?source=navbar) is compiled using a classical `./configure` `make` then `make install`.

If I just add the file to the corresponding source and include directory, I got this error message:

```
Settings.cpp:(.text+0x969) : undefined reference to ...
```

It looks like the makefile isn't able to produce the output file associated with my new source file (Source.cpp). So, I probably need to indicate it manually somewhere.

I searched a bit in the project files and it seemed that the file to edit was: "Makefile.am".
I added my source to the variable `iperf_SOURCES` in that file but it didn't workded.

Could you help me to find the file where I need to indicate my new source file (it seems a pretty standard compilation scheme but I never used automake softwares and this one seems very complicated).

Thank you in advance

Comment: your new source file is in some new directory or with the existing source files ? If you have changed the hierarchy then you need to update the same in make file.

Comment: No, the source.cpp is in the same directory as the previous sources. I added the source in the makefile.am in the same way than the other files.

Comment: are you sure about your new source not being compiled or you are assuming ?

Comment: I cant file the .o file of my specific source bur I can find it for each other source file

Comment: sometimes one makefile invokes another makefile which compiles the source file of some different/same module. Are you editing the correct makefile ?

Comment: The architecture of the program is the following: There are two makefiles, one in the root and one in the src subfolder. The root makefile just makes an inclusion of that one in the src folder. I edited those in src because the main one didn't specify any source file.

Comment: it's difficult to guess the problem without seeing the makefile. just to make sure if file is not compiling add some junk characters in new source file and compile via make. check the path of new source file in makefile if it is correct. try changing that path. it should throw file not found error. if nothing works you can write a separate makefile to compile your new source

Comment: The makefile.am is the following: 
http://pastebin.com/5V0TY5yu
I added the source: Mptcp.cpp

It seems that the source is correctly added. 
But, in the "true Makefile", the Makefile file, the modification seems to have to effect (the Makefile is the same when I add or remove the Mptcp source in Makefile.am)

Comment: add a space between "Mptcp.cpp" and "\" in your makefile and give it a try

Comment: I tried, it didn't changed anything. 
Even if I remove like 10 different sources at once from the .am file and then reconfigure (./configure), the output src Makefile will still remember then. It seems that there's a kind of "backup of the first version of the makefile" :s

Comment: can you provide your all makefiles and ./configure file ?

Comment: Of course. Here is the link (hope the link works, I never tried filedropper). 
http://www.filedropper.com/iperf-209mptcptar
Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120783/discussion-between-rafal-and-alexis-clarembeau).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project is built with the autotools, as you already figured out.

The makefiles are built by automake. It takes its input in files that usually have a `am` file name extension.

The iperf program is built by the makefile generated from `src/Makefile.am`. This is indicated by:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = iperf
```

All (*actually this is a simplification, but which holds in this case*) source files of a to be built binary are in the corresponding *name*_SOURCES variable, thus in this case `iperf_SOURCES`. Just add your source file to the end of that list, like so (keeping their formatting):

```
iperf_SOURCES = \
                Client.cpp \
# lines omitted
                tcp_window_size.c \
                my_new_file.c
```

**Now, to reflect this change in any future generated `src/Makefile` you need to run automake.** This will modify `src/Makefile.in`, which is a template that is used by `config.sub` at the end of `configure` to generate the actual makefile.

Running automake can happen in various ways:

- If you already have makefiles that were generated after an configure these *should* take care of rebuilding themselves. This seems to fail sometimes though!
- You could run automake (in the top level directory) by hand. I've never done this, as there is the better solution to...
- Run `autoreconf --install` (possibly add `--force` to the arguments) in the top level directory. This will regenerate the entire build system, calling all needed programs such as autoheader, autoconf and of course automake. **This is my favorite solution.**

The later two options require calling configure again, IMO ideally doing an out of source built:

```
# in top level dir 
mkdir build
cd build
../configure # arguments 
make # should now also compile and link your new source file
```

Comment: ´autoreconf --install´ worked like a charm. Thank you for your great answer :)